# Are there stats available to show which sites have the worst Migration record?

Tags: discussion, migration-rejection

I know that there are Migration (and Rejection) stats in the Moderator tools for individual sites.

But is there a resource to see these numbers across the network?

Has anyone done any analysis to find outliers in the numbers of rejections? Perhaps one site that gets a large portion of its Migrations rejected overall? Or one particular migration path that makes more trouble than it saves?

I'd think something like that would be useful in taking more time to educate the Moderators/community on such a site as to *how* to do Migrations.

(Just a little frustrated cleaning up another bad community Migration.)

Comment: Cleanup should be relatively straightforward nowadays; migrated questions that are closed on the target site now revert the migration history automatically on the source site.  Besides, whaddaya gonna do, pour hot wax over all of the offenders?  If a particular site's migration history is bothering you, post a question on their meta.

Comment: [This SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36489/how-valid-are-migrations) should work as a starting point, if you can get rid of the divide by zero error.

Comment: "If a particular site's migration history is bothering you, post a question on their meta." Oh, I've done that.